# How to Index Json files in azure cognitive search having more than 40 complex fields

Tags: json, azure, search, azure-cognitive-search, jsonlines

I have 1GB of Json files which I am trying to index using Azure Cognitive Search. On the very last step while creating an indexer I am getting an error saying, "The request is invalid. Details : Invalid index: The index contains 54 complex collection fields. An index can have at most 40 complex collection fields."

Microsoft support also mentioned that this is a product limitation.

Does anyone have faced this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Support is correct that indexes are limited to 40 complex collection fields. It's usually possible however to work around this limitation by excluding what doesn't strictly need to be in the index, or by modifying how the index fields are built and aggregated from data in the document: the portal wizard that suggests an index structure is an automated process that tries its best by sampling data in your datasource, but it doesn't understand what's important and what's not. An additional manual step over its suggestions is often necessary, and is an opportunity to optimize them to your specific requirements.

This doc article may also provide some useful suggestions: [How to model complex data types in Azure Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-complex-data-types)